# React Native - open links in browser

Tags: react-native

Hi i am using react native's webview to display some html,
i want that whenever a user clicks a link inside that html, it will open the user's browser with that link.

is that possible?

#### Edit 1:

I ended up using this package : npmjs.com/package/react-native-communications which opens the browser.
I call the browser to open on onNavigationStateChange when the URL changes.

The thing now is that the WebView still continues to process the request although I have moved to the browser, how can i stop the request?

Comment: Hi Matan, did you find a solution in the end? I am coping with the same issue, would be interested if there is a solution. I know in a UIWebView we can do this with a delegate implementation..

Answer (score 145):

Here is a complete working solution:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView, Linking } from 'react-native';

export default class WebViewThatOpensLinksInNavigator extends Component {
  render() {
    const uri = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531679/react-native-open-links-in-browser';
    return (
      <WebView
        ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
        source={{ uri }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
          if (event.url !== uri) {
            this.webview.stopLoading();
            Linking.openURL(event.url);
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

It uses a simple WebView, intercepts any url change, and if that url differs from the original one, stops the loading, preventing page change, and opens it in the OS Navigator instead.

[image: ios simulator]

Comment: This works for me, but I recommend to add `event.navigationType === 'click'` to the if condition to only catch click events in the browser...

Comment: This works for me only if I do ref in a different way - `ref="webview"` and then `this.refs.webview.stopLoading()`.

Comment: @Urska while this works for now, this way has been explicitly deprecated. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs. Also, both ways should work the same, so you may have another issue somehow.

Comment: @DamienVarron thanks for that notice, I was not aware of it. I guess I will have to do some more digging into my code. :)

Comment: @LaurenzGlück that would be really helpful, but don't see the property `navigationType` on the event, only `url`, `loading`, `canGoForward`, `canGoBack`, `target`, and `title`.  It's a little sloppy, but `canGoBack` works if you want to handle all links in the WebView and never let the user navigate inside the WebView.

Comment: use onShouldStartLoadWithRequest in the answer below. android 6 is buggy with this

Comment: @damusnet, I tried using and it has not worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400606/react-native-app-not-opening-news-article-links-in-separate-browser-but-instead

Comment: @damusnet, I am getting close to a solution with your fix, but getting `stopLoading` is undefined. Where is `stopLoading` defined in your solution?

Comment: For information, for now event.navigationType is implemented only on iOS, so can't work on android. So I open link in browser only if Platform.OS !== 'android'

Answer (score 56):

A big issue with using "stopLoading()" is that on Android it disables further taps on any other links from that source page.

The WebView component is being split out of core RN and into the community's hands. If you use that version instead (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview), you can use "onShouldStartLoadWithRequest" prop on both iOS and Android, which makes this a lot more elegant.

Building off of Damien Varron's really helpful answer, here's an example for how you'd leverage that prop to avoid stopLoading that works cross platform:

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => {
    if (event.url !== uri) {
        Linking.openURL(event.url)
        return false
    }
    return true
}}
```

And here's how you might do it if your source is HTML as opposed to a URI:

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => {
    if (event.url.slice(0,4) === 'http') {
        Linking.openURL(event.url)
        return false
    }
    return true
}}
```

As basbase pointed out, you could also do it this way (I've added the about:blank part). I plan to trial and error more to see which holds up best.

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => {
    if (!/^[data:text, about:blank]/.test(event.url)) {
        Linking.openURL(event.url)
        return false
    }
    return true
}}
```

Comment: great this really fixes lot of bugs. like preventing taps on original webview, or also sometimes the target websites displays some overlay over the original webview + it opens external browser.

Comment: `/^[data:text, about:blank]/` will match so many things because `[]` is a character class. You might have meant `/^(?:data:text|about:blank)/` instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51894818/1861779).

Answer (score 27):

```
Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

Comment: It works. Is there any way to open browser within an app just like modern apps are doing. I'm using expo

Comment: @MuhammadTalha you can use WebView for an embedded browser

Answer (score 19):

This is my solution. As it is not generic, you can improve the injected javascript according to your requirements

```
import {
  View,
  WebView,
  Linking,
} from 'react-native';

const injectScript = `
  (function () {
    window.onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.postMessage(e.target.href);
      e.stopPropagation()
    }
  }());
`;

class MyWebView extends React.Component {

  onMessage({ nativeEvent }) {
    const data = nativeEvent.data;

    if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
      Linking.openURL(data);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ html: this.props.html }}
        injectedJavaScript={injectScript}
        onMessage={this.onMessage}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `Setting onMessage on a WebView overrides existing values of window.postMessage, but a previous value was defined.`
How did you overcome this error? I keep getting this with your solution. There is an issue in react native repo for this as well - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10865.

Comment: It works like a charm. But the condition of `data !== "undefined"` should be added in `if` block.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: How do you use this? When I click a link I show MyWebView?

Comment: Thanks, very nice. But data !== undefined should be the string "undefined", not the type undefined.

Answer (score 11):

I found a way to do this, it is an iOS-only solution though!

Here is step-by-step instructions:

1. Link the `'RCTLinkingIOS'` library to your project. I used CocoaPods
   to so.
2. In your WebView add "onShouldStartLoadWithRequest". For example

   `<WebView source={{ html: content }} onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest} />`
3. Add the `this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` function. Return TRUE or FALSE based on whether or not you want to follow the link in your WebView. This is basically the equivalent of the UIWebViewDelegate implementation you would use when you implement it in native code (Swift or Objective-C).

   ```
   onShouldStartLoadWithRequest = (event) => {
        Linking.canOpenURL(event.url).then(supported => {
            if (supported) {
                Linking.openURL(event.url);
            } else {
                console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + event.url);
            }
            return false
        });
   }
   ```
4. Make sure to import Linking as well in your javascript source:

   `import { AppRegistry, View, WebView, Linking } from 'react-native';`

That should do the trick.

For more information see the react-native docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

Comment: This didn't work when any external services i.e. Youtube is embedded. It will autoplay when loaded and take you out of the app, then when you go back it'll bring you back to Youtube causing a loop.

Comment: As already mentioned above, onShouldStartLoadWithRequest 
 only exists on iOS https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onshouldstartloadwithrequest

Comment: onShouldStartLoadWithRequest worked with mobile browser chrome, using RN 6.14.6.

Answer (score 7):

@Damusnet's only worked sporadically for me. I looked into it and here's my updated code which works for me using react-native-webview 11.4.3.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { WebView, Linking } from 'react-native';

const WebviewScreen = () => {
  const uri = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531679/react-native-open-links-in-browser';

  return (
    <WebView
    source={{ uri }}
    onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(request) => {
      if (request.url !== uri) {
        Linking.openURL(request.url);
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }}
  />    
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<WebView
      source={{uri: this.state.src}}
      ref={(webView) => {
        this.webView.ref = webView;
      }}
      onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
        this.webView.canGoBack = navState.canGoBack;
        if (!navState.url.includes('yourdomain.com')) {
          Linking.openURL(navState.url);
          return false;
        }
      }}
      onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(event) => {
        if (!event.url.includes('yourdomain.com')) {
          Linking.openURL(event.url);
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      renderLoading={() => {
        return (
          <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
```

I struggled with this one, my use case was to open external links in a separate browser.  This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Solution for those who use expo:

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

...

render() {

    return (
        <WebView

            source={{
                uri: uri
            }}

            ref={ (ref) => { this.webview = ref; } }

            onNavigationStateChange={ (event) => {
                if (event.url !== uri) {
                    this.webView.stopLoading();
                    WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(event.url);
                }
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

`WebBrowser` is installed via: `expo install expo-web-browser`

Answer (score 3):

I had many issues with this solution while using local HTML file only at iOS.
For instance, when I had Instagram embed in my webview it opened it automatically.
In order to solve it I've added (only for iOS):

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => {
    const condition = isIos ? event.navigationType == 'click' : true
    if (event.url.slice(0, 4) === 'http' && condition) {
      Linking.openURL(event.url)
      return false
    }
  return true
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this in a cross-platform way using the built-in [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) class and [react-native-webview-bridge](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge).

```js
const generateLink = (text, url) => {
  if (url) {
    return `<a href='#' onclick='WebViewBridge.send("${url}"); return false;'>${text}</a>`;
  } else {
    return text;
  }
};

const generateHtml = () => `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
  ${generateLink('Link text', 'http://example.com')}
</body></html>`;
```

With a `WebViewBridge` component rendered like so:

```js
<WebViewBridge
  javaScriptEnabled
  renderLoading={() => <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />}
  source={{ html: generateHtml() }}
  onBridgeMessage={url => Linking.openURL(url)}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40382325/10236907:
When using `source={{html: '...'}}`, you can check for an external url change using:
`if (!/^data:text/.test(event.url)) {`

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are attempting to open a redirect url and you get an error from an android intent such as "err_unknown_url_scheme".
2. Check what it is trying to open because it may have detected android traffic and attempted to open in the corresponding app.
3. If you wish for it to open in the webview anyway and you get an intent back from a redirect, intercept it in onNavigationStateChange and rewrite it:

```
onNavigationStateChange={event => {
  if (event.url !== uri) {
      if (event.url.match('intent://')) {
          SetSearchClick(
              event.url.replace('intent://', 'https://'),
          );
         }
   }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linkingios.html

It is possible, just check the link above & you should be all good!

Other links:

https://github.com/ivanph/react-native-webintent

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-browser

Comment: it seems nice, but my first problem is that i don't know how to catch an event saying the user clicked on a link. is there such an event? do i need to use onNavigationStateChange event and check there?

Comment: Well I'm assuming that you're wanting to link <Text> to open up a certain link? What you can do is have a ```<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.function}> <Text>link goes here...</Text></TouchableHighlight> ```. This.function would be a function that would make use of the above npm packages. @MatanKadosh

Comment: no, you got me all wrong. i have a webview displaying html. the html might have links in it. i want that whenever the user clicks on a link he will be moved to the browser

Comment: I ended up using this package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-communications which opens the browser

Comment: Can I able to open the link in a popup window in react-native.(react-native-modal). If the user clicks on the url, it will redirect to another window outside the app. So I need to show the opened url in modal window. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can anyone check this question related with webview
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70520284/how-to-process-each-url-in-webview

Answer (score 0):

If `stopLoading()` in `onNavigationStateChange` on Android does not work,

```
this.webview.stopLoading();
setTimeOut( () => {
  Linking.openURL(event.url)
}, 1000);
```

It worked well.