# How to open links in Safari from React Native's WebView component

Tags: uiwebview, react-native

In the app, I'm using React Native's WebView component.  If the user clicks on any links explicitly I would like it to open in Safari, instead of the WebView component being directed to that URL.

```
 <WebView
    source={{uri: 'https://some-url-here'}}
    style={{marginTop: 20}}
  />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For IOS, you can use onShouldStartLoadWithRequest prop. The prop is called when webview is opening a new page. You can return false to stop loading and use React native Linking api to open url in safari.

Your onShouldStartLoadWithRequest could look like following:

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(navState)=>{
      Linking.openURL(navState.url)
      return false;
    }}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, that the exact conclusion I came. Using Linking does solve my problem. Thanks !

Comment: Android solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40382325/1828637 - linking for others