# How to open links that don't belong to my domain in browser - React Native Webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, expo

Hi I am using react native's webview to display a website url.
I want that when a user clicks a link inside the website(a line that doesn't belong to my domain), it will open the user's browser with that link.

If I have this domain example.com and if it change to something like that when I click a button example.com/about-us (This is ok)

But if I have this domain example.com and if it change to something like that when I click a button anotherdomain.com (This is should open in the user browser not in my webview app).

I have seen this subject but it don't give me what I need. I am using Expo in my webview app.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40382325/9776729

This is my code at now

This is a live demo https://snack.expo.io/@maher-aldous/webview

```
const appurl = 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native';

function UrlApp() {
  return (
      <WebView
        ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
        source={{uri: appurl}}
        onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
          if (event.url !== appurl) {
            this.webview.stopLoading();
            Linking.openURL(event.url);
          }
        }}
        startInLoadingState
        scalesPageToFit
        javaScriptEnabled
        style={{marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight}}
      />
  );
}
```

No errors

Comment: I don't understand, did you mean user click a link on the browser and open a page on your app on webview?

Comment: No. You know the webview apps are browsers but with your url only right. So let's say if I open up my webview app to browse through my site content and then I found a like that leads to google.com. I want that link open only in the Chrome etc... browsers not in my webview app. A webview app is like Iframe in HTML you have your url but if your url have another content thats leads to another website this will change your url to the that website and I don't want this happen in my webview app

Comment: It is recommended that link linkage be handled on the web instead of being handled by React-native.

Comment: Yes but this is a webview app so it's normal to have a link because it's a website inside a webview app. I just want to open the links that doesn't belong to my domain in the chrome or like that but not in my webview app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject JavaScript that will prevent links from opening and send the link back to RN instead using `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` and then open it with `Linking.openURL`.

Comment: Can you please rewrite the snack to get me forward because I don't have any idea of why should I use it in my app even after I have read the documentation in React and Expo