# How to open external link in browser from inside Webview in React Native?

Tags: react-native, webview

I have below webview component, I wanted the link to be opened in a mobile browser app rather than in inside current webview in my app.

```
return() {
    <WebView source={{ html: `<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>`}} />
}
```

Comment: Try adding `target="_blank"` to your anchor tag. BTW, `html` in `WebView` is Deprecated.

Comment: tried target="_blank" already, not working

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531679/react-native-open-links-in-browser

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

```
 import { WebView, Linking, NavState } from 'react-native';    

const html = ` 
 <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
 <a href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
`

class WebViewWrapper extends Component {
    private webview;

    handleNavigationStateChange = (event: NavState) => {
        if (event.url) {
            this.webview.stopLoading();
            Linking.openURL(event.url);
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <WebView
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                ref={ref => {
                   this.webview = ref;
                }}
                source={{ html }}
                onNavigationStateChange={this.handleNavigationStateChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do the same thing when I click on the webview

Answer (score 3):

you can do this:

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
```

on you launch function

```
Linking.openURL( some_url );
```

For more details, follow this full example: [Just what you want](https://medium.com/@elhardoum/opening-external-links-in-browser-in-react-native-webview-18fe6a66312a)

Answer (score 2):

Calling `stopLoading` freezes the WebView and links may stop working after pressing them once. Better to use `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` ([API Reference](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onshouldstartloadwithrequest)).

So the code could look something like this:

```js
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const html = ` 
 <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
 <a href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
`;

const shouldStartLoadWithRequest = (req) => {
  // open the link in native browser
  Linking.openURL(req.url);

  // returning false prevents WebView to navigate to new URL
  return false;
};

const MyComponent = () => (
  <WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html }}
    onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={shouldStartLoadWithRequest}
  />
);

export default MyComponent;
```

Note that `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` behaves a bit differently on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This will save your time and patience :)

```
 import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';
    <HTML
        html={this.state.content.description} 
        // imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width} 
        onLinkPress={(evt, href) => { Linking.openURL(href) }}
    />
```

- Fully supportive of android, ios and Expo too. And has some cool customisations you can try with.
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html