# Refactoring AutoHeightWebView library to get hyperlinks to open up in separate browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native application that I upgraded. Back when it was legacy, if you went to a news article and the article had hyperlinks and you clicked on the hyperlinks it would redirect you to your phones browser and open the link there, but it no longer does that because we had to upgrade the `react-native-autoheight-webview` library, so the patch that was done for the 0.6.1 version is now gone. That patch is what allowed hyperlinks to open in a separate browser.

I have been trying to repeat the process so we can get the same behavior. So I added this code to `node_modules/react-native-autoheight-webview/AutoHeightWebView/index.js` file:

```
const _onLoadStart = event => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.url.startsWith("http")) {
        this.stopLoading();
        Linking.openURL(event.nativeEvent.url).catch(err => console.log('An error occurred', err));
    } else {
        const {onLoadStart} = this.props;
        onLoadStart && onLoadStart(event);
    }
  }

    const { currentSource, script } = reduceData(props);

    const { width, height } = size;
    useEffect(
      () =>
        onSizeUpdated &&
        onSizeUpdated({
          height,
          width
        }),
      [width, height, onSizeUpdated]
    );



    return (
      <WebView
        {...props}
        ref={webView}
        onMessage={handleMessage}
        onLoadStart={_onLoadStart}
        style={[
          styles.webView,
          {
            width,
            height
          },
          style
        ]}
        injectedJavaScript={script}
        source={currentSource}
      />
    );
  }),
  (prevProps, nextProps) => !shouldUpdate({ prevProps, nextProps })
);
```

but that did nothing.

I also tried this in the same file:

```
const uri = `${media}/1.0/articles`;

    return (
      <WebView
        {...props}
        ref={webView}
        onMessage={handleMessage}
        source={{uri}}
        onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
          if (event.url !== uri) {
            this.webview.stopLoading();
            Linking.openURL(event.url);
          }
        }}
        style={[
          styles.webView,
          {
            width,
            height
          },
          style
        ]}
        injectedJavaScript={script}
        source={currentSource}
      />
    );
```

And nothing.

I cannot go back to `react-native-autoheight-webview@0.6.1` and do another patch package because that version is incompatible with React Native 60s versioning, namely we no longer use `index.ios.js/index.android.js` but instead `index.js`.

The earliest package of `react-native-autoheight-webview` would be 1.0.0 and it's a moot point by that version because the `WebView` and `Linking` module are no longer in the `react-native` library, but inside of `react-native-webview` library and it doesn't look like it supports the same properties to get a user to open a hyperlink in a separate browser as opposed to within the webview of the application. At least I have been unsuccessful in trying.

I also tried a complimentary package `react-native-webview-bridge` to come to the rescue but that package began crashing my application on both the iOS and Android side, so that was not a viable solution. Here are a couple of examples of how this approach failed:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_RCTJSNavigationScheme", referenced from:
      -[RCTWebViewBridgeManager constantsToExport] in libReact-Native-Webview-Bridge.a(RCTWebViewBridgeManager.o)
      -[RCTWebViewBridge webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] in libReact-Native-Webview-Bridge.a(RCTWebViewBridge.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

on the iOS side, on the Android side I got this error:

```
2019-10-17 13:01:14.292 15725-15839/com.nfibengage.dv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
    Process: com.nfibengage.dv, PID: 15725
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/react/views/webv
```

I guess at the end of the day, how do I successfully instruct my app to open an external link in an outside browser via communicating with React Native from the DOM?

I tried this configuration inside of `node_modules/react-native-autoheight-webview/AutoHeightWebView/index.js:

```
jsCode = () => {
   const attachEvent = function(elem, event, callback) {
     event = event.replace(/^on/g, '');
     if ('addEventListener' in window) {
       elem.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
     } else if ('attachEvent' in window) {
       elem.attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
     } else {
       const registered = elem['on' + event];
       elem['on' + event] = registered ? function(e) {
         registered(e);
         callback(e);
       } : callback;
     }

     return elem;
   }

   const all_links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]');
   
   if (all_links) {
     for (var i in all_links) {
       if (all_links.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
         attachEvent(all_links[i], 'onclick', function(e) {
           if (!new RegExp('^https?:\/\/' + location.host, 'gi').test(this.href)) {
             // handle external URL
             e.preventDefault();

             window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
               external_url_open: this.href
             }));
           }
         });
       }
     }
   }
 }



 render() {
   const { height, width } = this.state;
   const { style, originWhitelist } = this.props;
   const { source, script } = this.getUpdatedState(this.props, getBaseScript);
   return (
     <WebView
       {...this.props}
       originWhitelist={originWhitelist || ['*']}
       ref={this.webView}
       onMessage={this.onMessage}
       style={[
         styles.webView,
         {
           width,
           height
         },
         style
       ]}
       injectedJavaScript={this.jsCode}
       source={source}
     />
   );
 }
}
```

using this documentation as a guide:
https://medium.com/@elhardoum/opening-external-links-in-browser-in-react-native-webview-18fe6a66312a

It has done nothing for me.

Next I tried adding the `onNavigationStateChange` property to my `ActionAlertFeedCard`:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform
} from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { TextButton } from "react-native-material-buttons";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import format from "date-fns/format";
import { Card, Divider } from "common-components";
import { v2Colors, feedContentStyles, v2ButtonStyles } from "theme";
import { moderateScale } from "react-native-size-matters";

//prettier-ignore
const getHtml = content => `<body style="font-family: -apple-system, Roboto, sans-serif; font-size: ${moderateScale(32, 0.2)}px;">${content}</body>`;

const ActionAlertFeedCard = ({
  completed,
  content,
  datePosted,
  mainActionButtonPress,
  secondaryActionButtonPress,
  style,
  title
}) => (
  <Card style={style}>
    <View style={feedContentStyles.header}>
      <Text style={feedContentStyles.title}>{"ACTION ALERT"}</Text>
      <Text style={feedContentStyles.postDate}>
        {`${completed ? "Completed" : "Posted"} ${format(
          datePosted,
          "MMM D, YYYY"
        )}`}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <Divider />
    <View style={feedContentStyles.content}>
      <Text style={feedContentStyles.contentTitle}>{title}</Text>
      <WebView
        useWebKit={true}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        style={styles.webview}
        source={{
          html: getHtml(content)
        }}
        onNavigationStateChange={event => {
          console.log("url of webpage" + event.url);
        }}
        // scalesPageToFit={Platform.OS !== "ios"}
      />
```

The news articles never completed loading up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all hyperlinks to open in external browser then this method which you've tried should work:

```
onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
     console.log("url of webpage: "+ event.url);
          if (event.url !== uri) {
            this.webview.stopLoading();
            Linking.openURL(event.url);
          }
        }}
```

where uri is url of the article which you are loading initially. 
If it's not working then try keeping console log and check if that event is being fired or not.

There is no need to apply any patch or something, you can simple use react-native-autoheight-webview with react-native-webview.

There is guide about this on webview library page: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#controlling-navigation-state-changes

Comment: is `onNavigationStateChange` a property available to `AutoHeightWebView`? Its the instance of `AutoHeightWebView` that is responsible for rendering the articles. Please check out what I added above and thank you for your help.

Comment: this solution does seem to sort-of work. Your `uri` would be `undefined` in my context. I am implementing it inside of `ArticleDetails.js`, could you explain a bit more about what `uri` property is supposed to represent? Would it be `this.props.article` in my context?

Comment: I get `stopLoading` as undefined. Where would it be defined in your solution?

Comment: I found that I could pull this off without `this.webview.stopLoading();`. Thank you. Best 50 reputations I have spent so far :)

Comment: @Daniel 1. Yes `onNavigationStateChange` prop is available on `AutoHeightWebView` because we can use every prop of `react-native-webview`.
2. Actually i copied that snippet from your code itself. so `uri` will be the url of article which you want to load in your app.
3. You need to take ref of `webview` to use it's methods like this: 
`<WebView ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}`
Let me know if you have any other doubt.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me. To be able to utilize the `uri`, I had to create these variables: `const media = env.mediaServiceUrl;`, `const uri = `${media}/1.0/articles`;` and import `import env from "env";` and then I got it to work, and also pull out the `Linking` module from `react-native` library. Now the text in my webview is smaller, hopefully that is nothing major to fix, but your solution with some small tweaks works. Thank you.

Comment: one line of code I did not implement was `this.webview.stopLoading();` mainly because I was getting undefined for `webview`, but I see now that line is important for stopping the loading of the hyperlink inside of webview. You see now it loads on a separate external browser, but it also loads or still loads behind the scenes inside of webview. Now I understand what `this.webview.stopLoading();` does, but why is it undefined? To be clear I am not doing this inside an instance of `WebView` but inside an instance of `WebViewAutoHeight`

Comment: you need to store `ref` to get `AutoHeightWebView` instance like this: `<AutoHeightWebView ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}`

Comment: I already tried that and it did not work, instead I got a `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.webview.stopLoading')`. I suspect that is because the WebViewAutoHeight component doesn't expose a ref prop, so `this.webview` never gets set.