# How to process each url in webview

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

// ...
class MyWebComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} />;
  }
}
```

I am using this above code and i want to add some keys in the url like and some keys in this to process it. Like below

https://reactnative.dev/?daj

https://reactnative.dev/?meni

So this is working fine. But for initial url So i want that when i click on any link this url and this creates a new url like

https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started

so i want that it will add some keys in this like above

?daj

So i am not getting how can i do with this url to url moving within webview. Please check and let me know. Thanks

More detail:
I am loading google.com at starting and do some search on here

```
start url:google.com
Now url: google.com/
```

search='abc'

so i that i want process each url before load add some keys in it like below

```
google.com?key-base="abc"
google.com/search='abc'?key-base="abc"
```

OR

```
new-google.com?key-base="abc"
new-google.com/search='abc'?key-base="abc"
```

Comment: Hi, can you please, explain it further, I am not getting the problem statement.

Comment: @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN check more detail in the question

Comment: so after loading a url, if user click's on some other URL, you want to add some text on the clicked  URL. please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes, i want to add some text init but before loading not after

Comment: @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN  find anything? or is it tough to do...

Comment: I am taking a look.

Comment: found a solution, give me some time to type it out.

Answer (score 1):

> TLDR: working project [link](https://github.com/mrpmohiburrahman/react-native-webview-url-redirection)

There is a prop called [`onNavigationStateChange`](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onnavigationstatechange) which gives us `navState` object that includes the following properties

```
canGoBack
canGoForward
loading
navigationType (iOS only)
target
title
url
```

This `onNavigationStateChange` gives this object, anytime any URL opens.So this is suitable for your use case.

We've also got a prop called [`injectedJavaScript`](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#injectedjavascript).

Now we can use `onNavigationStateChange` to get the url to check for pattern matching and if it matches then we can call `injectJavaScript` using a ref to our `WebView` component and sent a string that looks like this

```
window.location = "www.example.com"
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
const webRef = useRef(null);

return (
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <View>
    <WebView
      ref={webRef}
      source={{ uri: "https://www.wikipedia.org/" }}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
        const { url } = navState; // extracting url from navState obj
        if (url.includes("https://www.wikipedia.org/")) {
          const newURL =
            "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=react+native";
          const redirectTo = 'window.location = "' + newURL + '"';
          webRef.current.injectJavaScript(redirectTo);
        }
      }}
    />
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
);
```

Here you can see that the source uri is `https://www.wikipedia.org/` but in `onNavigationStateChange` I am matching the string and redirects to this url `https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=react+native`

Comment: @Rambler, please, check if this solves your problem.

Comment: Not useful for more i already tried this solution as my new url will be https://www.wikipedia.org/?abc. So it fails here

Comment: @Rambler, ok, I will take another look

Comment: @Rambler, So, on browser  wikipedia.org/?abc this will fallback to defauld Wikipedia page, but on webview it's not doing that.