# react native bottom sheet bottom transparent

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { BottomSheet } from "react-native-btr";

export default function BottomSheetDemo() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  function toggle() {
    setVisible((visible) => !visible);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggle}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text>Toggle BottomSheet</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <BottomSheet
        visible={visible}
        onBackButtonPress={toggle}
        onBackdropPress={toggle}
      >
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text>Place your custom view inside BottomSheet</Text>
        </View>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 50,
    padding: 16,
  },
  card: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    height: 250,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

I am using the above code. So my problem is I am getting the bottom sheet as expected. And I want that it will 100px above the bottom. That is also working fine. But the thing is I am getting bottom and at top blur black background. But I want on the bottom margin-bottom 100. It will not show that black ground. I will start from marginbottom:100. But the bottom background will be transparent and I can do click on the bottom items.

Comment: So you want not to show the black background and margindBottom is 100. Am I right?

Comment: @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN i want to show 100px above from bottom. but i don't want to show background shadow at bottom.

Comment: so if you don't want to show background shadow that it'll reduce the shadow on both top and bottom of your bottom sheed.

Comment: if you want this then let me know.

Comment: that's the problem it removes shadow from bottom and top/ But i want to remove it from bottom only.

Comment: ok, let me try. I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN Sure let me know if we can connect and discuss.

Comment: give an hour or so.

Comment: got somewhat working solution for your problem, give me some time to write the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TLDR: working source [code](https://github.com/mrpmohiburrahman/transparentBottomSpacingModal). Be aware, this solution might get
> messy.

If we see the source [code](https://github.com/ThakurBallary/react-native-btr/blob/main/src/Components/BottomSheet.tsx) of `react-native-btr` then we will see that the [`BottomSheet`](https://github.com/ThakurBallary/react-native-btr/blob/b51d162d33bd387a3f5eb7951f90e90a2ed79d64/src/Components/BottomSheet.tsx#L14) component is actually a `Modal` component from `react-native-modal` passing 4 basic props to `react-native-modal` as shown below

```
<Modal
  isVisible={visible}
  onBackButtonPress={onBackButtonPress}
  onBackdropPress={onBackdropPress}
  style={{ justifyContent: "flex-end", margin: 0 }}
>
  {children}
</Modal>
```

So, what I did is, extract all the source [code](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal/tree/master/src) from `react-native-modal` which is just five files and modify this source code. I have put a new prop for `react-native-modal` called [`bottomSpacing`](https://github.com/mrpmohiburrahman/transparentBottomSpacingModal/blob/8c2a085eba33e25291206f2c2209e8ef3009c235/react-native-modal/src/modal.tsx#L719), so that user can change the bottom spacing.

Back in app.js the code is looking like this

```
  <Modal
    testID={"modal"}
    isVisible={isModalVisible}
    style={{ justifyContent: "flex-end", margin: 0 }} // this line was using in react-native-btr source
    bottomSpacing={BOTTOM_SPACING}>
    <View style={styles.card}>
      <Text>Place your custom view inside BottomSheet</Text>
    </View>
  </Modal>
```

Here, `BOTTOM_SPACING` is used both in `bottomSpacing` props and the `styles.card` as following

```
  card: {
    marginBottom: BOTTOM_SPACING,
    ...
  }
```

Bonus: Now you can use all the [features](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal#available-props) of `react-native-modal` such as changing the color of the shadow and the opacity of that shadow etc.

Comment: @Rambler, please, accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: So i have to make this code in my code folder.

Comment: I have also some more questions added if you want to check. Also i will love your upvotes.

Comment: @Rambler, no worries, I am checking those now.

Comment: @Rambler, I wish there is a way to send direct messages here.

Comment: @Rambler, also, if you want help in any specific question, then mention it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70520284/how-to-process-each-url-in-webview

Comment: Please check the mentioned question.

Comment: @Rambler, ok...